# How to separate a field ussing awk by letter or end character

Tags: linux, bash, perl, awk, grep

i have a 2 fields in my DB

```
ID25333,1429291340lNormPUC-AP_MEX_UFM-GOL_44PUC-AP_VEX_UFM-ROL_55PUCAP_MEX_UFM-DOJ_49
ID55555,1429291340lNormPUC-AP_PPP_UFM-HOL_44PUC-AF_GEX_UJM-SOL_45PUCAP_MEX_UFM-DOJ_59
```

and i need separate like this

```
ID25333,PUC-AP_MEX_UFM-GOL_44     
ID25333,PUC-AP_VEX_UFM-ROL_55
ID25333,PUCAP_MEX_UFM-DOJ_49
ID55555,PUC-AP_PPP_UFM-HOL_44
ID55555,PUC-AF_GEX_UJM-SOL_45
ID55555,PUCAP_MEX_UFM-DOJ_59
```

with the same numbre ID

i using the AWK  or grep

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="PUC"}{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)print $(i)}'
```

any suggestions

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With GNU awk:

```
$ awk -F, '{gsub(/PUC/, ","); for (i=3;i<=NF;i++)print $1",PUC"$i}' file.db
ID25333,PUC-AP_MEX_UFM-GOL_44
ID25333,PUC-AP_VEX_UFM-ROL_55
ID25333,PUCAP_MEX_UFM-DOJ_49
ID55555,PUC-AP_PPP_UFM-HOL_44
ID55555,PUC-AF_GEX_UJM-SOL_45
ID55555,PUCAP_MEX_UFM-DOJ_59
```

Or:

```
$ awk -F'(,|PUC)' '{for (i=3;i<=NF;i++)print $1",PUC"$i}' file.db
ID25333,PUC-AP_MEX_UFM-GOL_44
ID25333,PUC-AP_VEX_UFM-ROL_55
ID25333,PUCAP_MEX_UFM-DOJ_49
ID55555,PUC-AP_PPP_UFM-HOL_44
ID55555,PUC-AF_GEX_UJM-SOL_45
ID55555,PUCAP_MEX_UFM-DOJ_59
```

Comment: FYI There;s nothing gawk-specific in those solutions.

Answer (score 0):

If you like `awk`

```
awk -F, ' -v OFS=','
{
  id=$1
  split($2,line,"PUC")
  for(i=2;i<=length(line);i++)
    print id,"PUC" line[i]
}'
```

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for fixed width fields:

```
$ awk -v FIELDWIDTHS="8 15 21 21 21" '{for (i=3;i<=NF;i++) print $1 $i}' file
ID25333,PUC-AP_MEX_UFM-GOL_44
ID25333,PUC-AP_VEX_UFM-ROL_55
ID25333,PUCAP_MEX_UFM-DOJ_49
ID55555,PUC-AP_PPP_UFM-HOL_44
ID55555,PUC-AF_GEX_UJM-SOL_45
ID55555,PUCAP_MEX_UFM-DOJ_59
```